# Determine whether V and W are isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

This was a homework problem that my TA graded but I don't understand why he marked it incorrect. Here is my problem and work:

$V=S_{3}$(symmetric 3x3 matrix ) and $W = s_{3}^{\prime}$ (skew symmetric 3x3 matrix)

I determined the dim of $V = 6 * \frac{3(3+1)}{2}$
However, the dim of W is 3. 
So, i said since dim V does not equal to dim W then they are not isomorphic

Comment: This is correct (though I think you made typos in your post). Vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. I'm not sure why your TA marked it incorrectly but I would contact him/her and discuss it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I just wanted to make sure I was correct before I approached him.

Comment: What was the problem to be solved?

Comment: That is the problem. That is the only information they gave us and I posted it all in the question.

Comment: Was the problem to determine whether $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, you have to determine whether V and W are isomorphic

Comment: OK. $V$ and $W$ are indeed not isomorphic, but the dimension of $V$ is 6, not 36. That may be why you lost marks.

Comment: Agreed with Brad...you have three independent parameters on the diagonal and three independent parameters off-diagonal, that's it - so dim$(V)=6$